# Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found ( Local pyspark submit )

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am using spark 3.2.1
Hadoop version =3.3.1
(sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo.getVersion())

I saw in other forums that this error is received because of incorrect pyspark packages.
The packages that I am using to run pyspark are as below

```
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.901,
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1,
net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.13.10,
net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.9.2-spark_3.1 
pyspark-shell
```

command running: `spark-submit --master local[3] main.py`

I am only getting this error when I run using spark-submit. When I run it in vs code (clicking on run) it is not giving any errors.

Error received:

```
Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
```

Why am I getting this error, are the packages wrong, where can I check package dependency with my pyspark version?

Comment: Think you may need to pass the aws jar with the --jars parameter or similar

Comment: it is working, buy why is it not working when I give it in configuration file?